# How to find the formula of the infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to find the formula of the infinite sum of the following series? The given series is $$S=(1-\frac{1}{3^{2}})+(\frac{1}{2^{2}}-\frac{1}{4^{2}})+.\dots$$ mAs far as I have guessed, the $n^{th}$ term of the given series is $(\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^{2}})$. Also I guessed that the above summation can be $\frac{5}{4}$. Because the terms $\frac{1}{3^{2}},\frac{1}{4^{2}},\frac{1}{5^{2}}...$ will cancel out(since the above series is upto $\infty$). But still I am confused with my answer. Please help me out with the above summation.

Comment: Yes you are correct ... but do note you are actually using results about series in your reasoning.

Comment: "Above" usually means the series comes before the question. Here you want "the following series..." rather than "the above series..."

Comment: @Syamaprasad Chakrabarti Use the idea that this is a telescoping sum, and find the partial sum sequence.

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that two terms don’t suffice to uniquely determine an infinite series. It is indeed the case that your two terms do fit the general form you “have guessed.” But there are also infinitely more other general forms that those terms fit just as well. Most of those others could fairly be described as more  and more outlandish, but they are no less valid for their complexity.

Comment: What are you trying to say @PaulTanenbaum?

Comment: What I am saying (and not merely “trying to say”) is illustrated by the fact that “$2+4+\cdots$” is ambiguous. It could mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n$, and $2n$ and $2^n$ are certainly not the only general forms of terms in infinite series that begin with $2+4$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum,I agree,The famous moser's circle problem has series 1,2,4,6,8,16,31,57,99,163...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write the series $S$ as the limit of a finite *telescoping* sum. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S}&=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)+
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{(N+2)^2}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{5}{4}}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S_n=\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{6^2}.......\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{{(n+2)}^2}$$

Which can be written as

$$S_n$$

$$={\frac{1}{1^2}-} \require{cancel}\cancel{{\frac{1}{3^2}}}$$

$$+{\frac{1}{2^2}-}\cancel{\frac{1}{4^2}}$$

$$+\cancel{\frac{1}{3^2}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{5^2}}$$

$$+\cancel{\frac{1}{4^2}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{6^2}}$$

$$.$$$$.$$$$.$$$$.$$$$$$

$$+\cancel{\frac{1}{(n-2)^2}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{{(n^2)}}}$$

$$+\cancel{\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}}-\frac{1}{{(n+1)^2}}$$

$$+\cancel{\frac{1}{(n)^2}}-\frac{1}{{(n+2)^2}}$$

Hence $$S_n=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{1}{{(n+1)^2}}-\frac{1}{{(n+2)^2}}$$

Now taking limit when $n\to\infty$

$$S_{\infty}=\frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: Was the downvote for Mathjax issues?